# How to implement Method that calls itself?

Tags: c#, recursion, loops

I got my wrist slapped because in an assignment i had a method call itself when an input error was made. I have no idea how to or what to use instead of the code i wrote. I need help to find the correct way on how to do it.

I love to code so i just need a nudge in the right way! :)

The code i had written looks like this.

```
 private void SumTheNumbers()
 {
 Console.Write("Please give the value no "+ index + " :");
        if (false == int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
        { 
            //Errormessage if the user did not input an integer.
            Console.WriteLine("Your input is not valid, please try again.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            sum = 0;
            SumTheNumbers();
        }
        else
        {
            //Calculate the numbers given by user
            sum += num;
        }
  }
```

Comment: I assume they were expecting an explicit loop?

Comment: Are you looking for a loop? See e.g. the `while` keyword.

Comment: A much worse style problem with this code is the use of global variables.

Comment: @BenVoigt - They are likely accessing a class member from a private method. I don't see an issue with this. Ideally though I try and keep my functions as pure as possible but you can't always do this.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: There's no good reason for `num` to be a class member, and several reasons for it to be a local.  It's bad style.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I agree but you are making assumptions about our friends code as well as making a blanket statement that they will undoubtedly not understand given the program. They will need context and examples for your comment to be of any use.

Comment: Your method is never popped from the stack before pushing a clone on top of it. Your stack is full of minions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard way to implement this would be with a while loop.

```
int num;
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your input is not valid, please try again.\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! num is a gonner ;) i moved it for better style :) I Tried to get both while and switch/case work before but i couldent thou now i have a while loop running and working. There is soo much for me to learn about coding and there seem to be more the more i learn.

Comment: @user1501127 - Just keep your head up and remember we all have to start from zero.

Answer (score 8):

Personally I kind of like that style, but it *is* inefficient (and could potentially result in a stack overflow, if the user entered invalid input a huge number of times). Your instructor probably wanted you to use a `while` loop:

```
Console.Write("Please give the value no "+ index + " :");
while (false == int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
{ 
    //Errormessage if the user did not input an integer.
    Console.WriteLine("Your input is not valid, please try again.");
    Console.WriteLine();
    sum = 0;
}

//Calculate the numbers given by user
sum += num;
```

By the way, that `false ==` bit is very non-idiomatic, and would raise eyebrows on most teams (as a side note: if your instructor advised you to write that, he/she probably comes from a different language background where it's a safeguard against accidental assignment; trust me, it's not necessary or normal in C# land). This looks a lot more typical:

```
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
{
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: In C you can run into the unfortunate problem with explicit equality checks and "boolean values" (say `TRUE == SomeMethod()` and SomeMethod returns -1 instead of !0). Boolean values simply should not be explicitly tested against 'false' or 'true'.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: In C, `1 == !0`.  Maybe you meant `-1`, or `~0`?

Comment: @sixlettervariables: You're right; I conflated two issues. I reworded the comment to not misleadingly single out the C language.

Comment: Haha, well i have switched to while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
just so i raise less eyebrows! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use a while loop.

```
Console.Write("Please give the value no "+ index + " :");
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))   //I find "!" easier to read then "false == "
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your input is not valid, please try again.");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Please give the value no "+ index + " :");
}
```

There is no need for recursion here, so a do while loop is better.

Comment: @sixlettervariables OP states "I love to code so i just need a nudge in the right way! :)"  I nudge is something to the effect of "You should look at a loop."  You should learn how to answer the actual problem instead of nitpicking other people.

Comment: I think the variable just adds way too much syntactic noise.

Comment: @ChaosPandion yeah, it was a quick write.  I originaly wanted to use a do loop, then realized that the "Please give..." text would have to be printed again, so I wrote it the other way.